# How do I use an include_path with an insert query

Tags: php

The program works everything is fine and running and even inserting the information. However, when you click the register button it displays the goodReg.inc file and puts the die message for the mysqli_query afterwards..So basically it says that the User registered successfuly, but couldn't connect to the login server.

URL = www.cameronwebsites.com/php/lesson5/register.php

My Code:

```
<?php
 /* connection info */
ini_set("include_path","../../includes");
include("dbinfo.inc");
$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname) 
    or die("Couldn't connect to server.");
?>

foreach($good_data as $field => $value)
        {
            $good_data[$field] = mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn,$value);
        }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO UserInfo (user_id, password, first_name, last_name, city, country, email) VALUES ('$good_data[user_id]', '$good_data[password]', '$good_data[first_name]', '$good_data[last_name]', '$good_data[city]', '$good_data[country]', '$good_data[email]')";
include('goodReg.inc');
            $result = mysqli_query($cxn,$sql) or die("<p>**Couldn't connect to login server**</p>");     
            $row = mysqli_fetch($result);
             if ($row > 0)
            {
                $sql2 = "UPDATE TimeStamp SET time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP where user_id='$good_data[user_id]'";  
                   $result2 = mysqli_query($cxn,$sql2) or die("<p>Couldn't Connect to Login</p>");

            }
            else
            {
                echo $message;
                extract($good_data);
                include('register.inc');
                exit();
            } 
        }   
    }
    else
    {
      include("register.inc");
    }



The $result = mysqli_query is where the connection dies, but not sure why
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to get rid of the mysqli_fetch function as you cannot use that function with an INSERT query.

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO UserInfo (user_id, password, first_name, last_name, city, country, email) VALUES ('$good_data[user_id]', '$good_data[password]', '$good_data[first_name]', '$good_data[last_name]', '$good_data[city]', '$good_data[country]', '$good_data[email]')";
    mysqli_query($cxn, $sql) or die ("Couldn't insert into UserInfo: " . mysqli_error($cxn));

            $sql2 = "UPDATE TimeStamp SET time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP where user_id='$good_data[user_id]'";  
               $result2 = mysqli_query($cxn,$sql2) or die("Couldn't update TimeStamp: " . mysqli_error($cxn));
```